# Console Exception and converting fatal errors into exception with ExceptionHandler

Tags: symfony, exception, error-handling, console, command

my goal is to save exceptions and errors that occured during a console command.

I'm using console.exception native symfony event, registered as follow :

```
kernel.listener.console:
        class: Evo\CronBundle\EventListener\ConsoleListener
        arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: console.exception, method: onConsoleException }
```

i'm running the following custom command :

```
<?php
namespace Evo\CronBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Evo\CronBundle\Event\CustomConsoleCommandEvent;
use Evo\CronBundle\Event\CustomConsoleTerminateEvent;
use Evo\CronBundle\Event\CustomConsoleExceptionEvent;
use Evo\CronBundle\EvoCronEvents;


class SendPostRegistrationMail1Command extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    /**
     * Configure command
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('evo:send_post_registration_mail_1')
            ->setDescription('Send Post Registration mail #1')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * Execute command
     *
     * @param InputInterface $input
     * @param OutputInterface $output
     * @return int|null|void
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        throw new \Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException('test');
    }
}
```

The exception thrown triggers the event, where I can dump the exception I'll save into database :

```
<?php

namespace Evo\CronBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Event\ConsoleExceptionEvent;
use Evo\CronBundle\Entity\CommandException;

class ConsoleListener
{
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    private $em;

    /**
     * @var \Evo\CronBundle\Entity\CommandExecution
     */
    private $commandExecution;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param EntityManager $em
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * onConsoleException
     *
     * @param ConsoleExceptionEvent $event
     */
    public function onConsoleException(ConsoleExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        $exception = $event->getException();

        echo '<pre>';
        \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($exception);
        echo '</pre>';
        die();
    }
}
```

displays

```
object(stdClass)#548 (6) {
  ["__CLASS__"]=>
  string(53) "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException"
  ["message"]=>
  string(4) "test"
  ["code"]=>
  int(0)
  ["file"]=>
  string(94) "C:\server\www\evoportail-zfony\src\Evo\CronBundle\Command\SendPostRegistrationMail1Command.php"
  ["line"]=>
  int(59)
  ["severity"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

In that case, the exception is correctly filled with message and the exception class is the one I threw in my command.

But if I purposely triggers a php fatal error to make Symfony convert it into an exception using Exceptionhandler, for example :

```
/**
     * Execute command
     *
     * @param InputInterface $input
     * @param OutputInterface $output
     * @return int|null|void
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        strpos();
    }
```

The exception dumped in my event is the following :

```
object(stdClass)#642 (6) {
  ["__CLASS__"]=>
  string(48) "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\DummyException"
  ["message"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["code"]=>
  int(0)
  ["file"]=>
  string(98) "C:\server\www\evoportail-zfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler.php"
  ["line"]=>
  int(162)
  ["severity"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

It's a DummyException thrown in \Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler.php and it has nothing related to the error triggered in my command. Did I miss something about this ErrorHandler supposed to convert errors into exceptions ?